# Unusual behaviour with changePage on android 2.3.6

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am building a phonegap app with jquery mobile and using build.phonegap.com

I have an event to change the page to the login screen after startup process have completed.

This works fine but it will not work on my andriod device unless a debugger is attached to it, in which case it works fine.

The code I have is

```
$.mobile.changePage("login.html");
```

I have put this in the mobileinit, pageshow, and now on document.ready function but it doesnt change the behaviour.

I've checked if $.mobile is a function and it is, Have tried everything and can not seem to figure out why this would be happening, any feedback would be much appreciated

Comment: I would listen device ready in mobileinit and then do the changepage in ondeviceready function.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to put in a hack to work around this issue.

It was something to do with my phone being really old and slow, so something was getting a little messed up on old/slow andriod versions.

To prevent this from being an Issue I figured out this way that solves the issue and boots up my jquery mobile app on phone gap even if the phone is very slow.

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var html = $(".loading-status-text").html();
        /* The html has Please Wait in the dom so we know it han't been touched by jQuery */
        if (html == 'Please Wait') {
            window.location.href = 'index.html';
        }
    }, 10000);

    $(document).on("pageshow", function (e) {
        var pageId = $.mobile.activePage.attr('id').toString();
        if (pageId == 'loadingScreen') {
            /* This wouldn't fire at first */
            $(".loading-status-text").html("Welcome to Appname");
            $.mobile.changePage("login.html");
        }
    });
});
```